# Does every facebook user have a username?

Tags: facebook, authentication

I want to use fb login and the user's facebook username on my website. However, I need the username to be non-blank.

Is it safe to assume that every facebook user has a username (that I can get through the graph API), and no user has a blank username?

Answer (score 3):

### No. You should not assume that everyone has defined a username...

There are still some users who have not yet [defined their usernames](https://www.facebook.com/username/). A much better solution would be to require your users to login using their email address as a username. This will always be unique (as email addresses are).

The [email address permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) can be request from your users and after that you'll be able to access it through -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id?fields=email
```

Comment: I think for every user that has not set a username for themselves, Facebook has nowadays given one of their own making.

Comment: @cbr - When specifically requesting the username of a user that has not set a username, only the id parameter is returned - as is the same behavior for any other field you don't have access to. The id can be used the same as a username though with regard to the users profile page - facebook.com/user_id will point to that users profile.

Comment: Keep in mind that the email field returned by Facebook can be blank as well. Facebook registrations do not require email, so long as one provides a phone number.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using openid login or facebook login in your case, you always get at minimum the `email` of the user, so you could use that as your username, because new users in facebook can't have username, but they have a `user id` which is a messy number for example in this case:

```
{
   "id": "10525827",
   "name": "xxxxx",
   "first_name": "first",
   "last_name": "last",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/username",
   "username": "username",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "es_LA"
}
```

So you the `id` is always unique, and the `username`as well.